# list of tags overlay

Tags: terms

I have an overlay of project's tags, and I want to display them like a list and NOT with a coma like it appears bellow, in the attachment.
Here is the code :

```
<p class="nom"> <?php echo strip_tags (get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'project_tag', '',', ')); ?></p>
```

Any idea ?
I already tried to insert a

```
<br>
```

but it s not working...
Thanks !

[image]

! UPDATE , here is all the code :

```
    if ( '' !== $thumb ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php if ( 'on' !== $fullwidth ) : ?>
            <span class="et_portfolio_image">
        <?php endif; ?>
                <?php print_thumbnail( $thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height ); ?>
        <?php if ( 'on' !== $fullwidth ) : ?>
                <div class="meta">  
                <span class="et_overlay">   
                <?php if ( 'on' === $show_project_tag) : ?>

                <p class="unfilmde">        <?php echo esc_html__( 'Skills', 'Divi' ); ?></p>
                <p class="nom"> <?php echo strip_tags (get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'project_tag', '',', ')); ?></p>

                <?php endif; ?></span>
                </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the `strip_tags()` will remove all HTML tags.

If you want to allow `<br>`, then you can add it as the second input parameter:

```
echo strip_tags( $text, '<br>' );
```

> I want to display them like a list

For that case, you could try this example:

```
<p class="nom">
    <ul>
        <?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'project_tag', '<li>', '</li><li>', '</li>' ); ?>
    </ul>
</p>
```

where `the_terms()` uses the `get_the_term_list()`.

**Update:**

Here's how you could replace the commas (,) with `<br>`:

```
<p class="nom">
    <?php 
         $tmp = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'project_tag', '', '<br>', '' );
         echo strip_tags( $tmp, '<br>' );  
    ?>
</p>
```

but regarding the `<ul>` list I think it's an CSS issue.

Comment: Hi thank you ! But I tried the last example and the tags aren't displayed overlay but bellow the picture.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "showing overlay". You may need to modify the `<ul>`-list with some CSS.

Comment: I updated the initial question with the entire code of the thumbnail.

Comment: Changed the ul in CSS but the tags still don't appear over the picture... But if it is only a css issue, I will find how to do I hope. Thank you anyway

Comment: Thank you fort your update, but it brokes all my theme !

Comment: ahh, there was a spelling error in `get_the_terms_list`, should have been `get_the_term_list`, I updated it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$terms = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'project_tag', '<ul><li>','</li><li>','</li></ul>');
```

This will generate the list of tags in ul/li format. Like

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">asdf1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">asdf2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">asdf3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you ! But if I put this code, any tag is displaying...!

Comment: I updated the initial question with the entire code of the thumbnail.